# mplayer (via console) doesn't always show audio file duration - how to change behaviour?

Tags: console, mplayer

I use mplayer principally to play audio files from the Linux console.  Most of the time, mplayer happily shows me the duration of the file and the runtime so far (note: I've paused both playbacks just to let me copy/paste the output):

```
jim@brisbane /public/podcasts/AmateurRadio/Linux in the Ham Shack $ mplayer lhs150.ogg 
MPlayer 1.2.1 (Debian), built with gcc-5.3.1 (C) 2000-2016 MPlayer Team
mplayer: could not connect to socket
mplayer: No such file or directory
Failed to open LIRC support. You will not be able to use your remote control.

Playing lhs150.ogg.
libavformat version 56.40.101 (external)
libavformat file format detected.
[lavf] stream 0: audio (vorbis), -aid 0, LHS Episode #150: The Sesquicentennial
Load subtitles in ./
==========================================================================
Opening audio decoder: [ffmpeg] FFmpeg/libavcodec audio decoders
libavcodec version 56.60.100 (external)
AUDIO: 44100 Hz, 1 ch, floatle, 80.0 kbit/5.67% (ratio: 10000->176400)
Selected audio codec: [ffvorbis] afm: ffmpeg (FFmpeg Vorbis)
==========================================================================
AO: [pulse] 44100Hz 1ch floatle (4 bytes per sample)
Video: no video
  =====  PAUSE  =====
A:  16.4 (16.3) of 5404.9 ( 1:30:04.9)  0.4%
```

You can see, above, that I am 16.4 seconds in out of 5404.9, but more importantly, I can see that the podcast in this case is 1:30:04.9 in duration.

```
jim@brisbane ~/hobart/server/podcasts/MUSIC/PODCASTS/Linux in the Ham Shack $ mp lhs203.ogg 
MPlayer 1.2.1 (Debian), built with gcc-5.3.1 (C) 2000-2016 MPlayer Team
mplayer: could not connect to socket
mplayer: No such file or directory
Failed to open LIRC support. You will not be able to use your remote control.

Playing lhs203.ogg.
libavformat version 56.40.101 (external)
libavformat file format detected.
[mjpeg @ 0x7f6a2fda03c0]Changeing bps to 8
[lavf] stream 0: audio (vorbis), -aid 0, LHS Episode #203: Choosing Your Linux Distribution
[lavf] stream 1: video (mjpeg), -vid 0
VIDEO:  [MJPG]  300x300  0bpp  90000.000 fps    0.0 kbps ( 0.0 kbyte/s)
Load subtitles in ./
==========================================================================
Opening video decoder: [ffmpeg] FFmpeg's libavcodec codec family
libavcodec version 56.60.100 (external)
Selected video codec: [ffmjpeg] vfm: ffmpeg (FFmpeg MJPEG)
==========================================================================
==========================================================================
Opening audio decoder: [ffmpeg] FFmpeg/libavcodec audio decoders
AUDIO: 44100 Hz, 1 ch, floatle, 80.0 kbit/5.67% (ratio: 10000->176400)
Selected audio codec: [ffvorbis] afm: ffmpeg (FFmpeg Vorbis)
==========================================================================
AO: [pulse] 44100Hz 1ch floatle (4 bytes per sample)
Starting playback...
[mjpeg @ 0x7f6a2fda03c0]Changeing bps to 8
Movie-Aspect is 1.00:1 - prescaling to correct movie aspect.
VO: [vdpau] 300x300 => 300x300 Planar YV12 
Movie-Aspect is 1.00:1 - prescaling to correct movie aspect.
VO: [vdpau] 300x300 => 300x300 Planar YV12 
No pts value from demuxer to use for frame!
pts after filters MISSING
A:3615.6 V:  53.8 A-V:3561.850 ct:  0.025   0/  0  0%  0%  2.4% 0 0 1.50x 
  =====  PAUSE  =====
```

This episode differs by popping up a little window with a logo of the podcast (Linux in the Ham Shack), so it seems mplayer is treating it as a video file of some sort instead of a plain audio file.  Note also, however, that the output does *not* show the duration of the file anymore.  In fact, the text display is totally different.

I don't need the text display to be identical, but I do want to see the time remaining.  Is there some way to force this to work?

If you want sample audio files, I used Linux in the Ham Shack episodes #150 and #203.  (I have nothing to do with this podcast except being a listener.)

I run Debian/Ubuntu/Mint but OS seems to have little to do with this.

Suggestions?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just disable the video output:

mplayer -novideo lhs243.ogg

Comment: That did it.  Somehow, poring through the entire man page, I didn't find that option.  Thank you.